# ts-node requires newrelic.js instead of node module

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, newrelic, ts-node

I'm running a CLI script that requires the New Relic agent as its first thing:

```js
require('newrelic')
import { CommandModule, CommandService } from 'nestjs-command'

(async () => {
  const app = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(ConsoleModule, {
  // ...
```

It happens that I have a `newrelic.js` file on the root folder that holds NR's configs, and instead of the `require` loading the `newrelic` node module, it's loading the JS file instead.

This is the yarn command I'm running:

```
"console:dev": "ts-node-dev -r tsconfig-paths/register --files src/cli.ts"
```

Any idea of how to make the module have precedence over the JS file?

It only fails with ts-node/ts-node-dev/npx - Nestjs's start command fetches the New Relic module properly.

Comment: What's the version of your `@nestjs/cli`? [It looks like this should be fixed as of 7.5.2](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/838)

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I'm running 7.5.4 sadly. I'll have a look at this discussion to see if it helps.

Comment: Heya @Isouza, did you find a solution? It happened to me with `ts-node` and `tsconfig-paths` (no `nestjs`) too.